# LooseVersion instance has no attribute version - awx installation in openshift error

Tags: ansible, openshift, ansible-awx

I am following the official documentation to install awx in openshift https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md. The steps are under `Openshift install steps`.

When I update the inventory file and run `ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml` I get the following error in Task `TASK [kubernetes : Use correct cli option for kubeconfig]` (please refer to the step [here](https://github.com/ansible/awx/search?q=Use%20correct%20cli%20option%20for%20kubeconfig&unscoped_q=Use%20correct%20cli%20option%20for%20kubeconfig))

ERROR:
`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Version comparison: LooseVersion instance has no attribute 'version'"}`

Using ansible version:

```
ansible 2.9.7
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5
```

I am not able to find any solutions online, any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: Output of `oc version` and `oc version | sed -n 's/oc v//p'` is in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Seems like the version of your `oc` binary cannot be determined. Is the `oc` binary installed? Can you add the output for `oc version` and `oc version | sed -n 's/oc v//p'?

Comment: Hi @Simon, I've edited the question and added a output image of both the commands. `oc version | sed -n 's/oc v//p'` doesn't give me anything - returns  nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the output. So it seems that the installer does not properly work with an `oc` client version 4. I would recommend the following: 1) Temporarily install a `oc` client version 3.11 to install AWX. 2) Open a new Issue with your description and output above in the AWX installer repo so it can be fixed: https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues

Comment: @Simon Thanks! I've created an issue, let me see what they come back with. Here's the link - https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/7053

Comment: @Simon the reason `oc version | sed -n 's/oc v//p'` didn't print anything was because of the `-n` flag (silenced). This `oc version | sed 's/oc v//p'` prints out exactly as`oc version`. Anyway, I found a workaround. I've posted as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I hard-coded this [step](https://github.com/ansible/awx/search?q=Use%20correct%20cli%20option%20for%20kubeconfig&unscoped_q=Use%20correct%20cli%20option%20for%20kubeconfig) to use `--kubeconfig` as I know my version is 4.2 (above 3.11)

Just set `oc_kubeconfig_option: '--kubeconfig'` and I was successfully able to deploy an AWX instance.